# How do I pass php array to vuejs component

Tags: php, arrays, vuejs2

I want to pass a php array to a vuejs component.

Here is how I am doing it.

```html
<?php
  $number = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
?>

<!-- My vue js component -->

<orderform :orderd="formdata"></orderform>

<script>
  const app = new Vue({
      el: '#orderform',
      data(){
        return {
            formdata: <?php $number ?>
        }
      }
  });
</script>
```

Below is the error I am getting in the console

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }**

When I use it like below. It works fine with no errors.

```html
<?php
  $number = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
?>

<!-- My vue js component -->

<orderform :orderd="formdata"></orderform>

<script>
  const app = new Vue({
      el: '#orderform',
      data(){
        return {
            formdata: ['one', 'two', 'three']
        }
      }
  });
</script>
```

I will appreciate for any help. Thanks

Comment: @kikuyu1 check answer of Jacob Goh. It will solve your problem

Comment: @B.Desai Thank you. my problem is solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script>
  const app = new Vue({
      el: '#orderform',
      data(){
        return {
            formdata: <?php print json_encode($number) ?>
        }
      }
  });
</script>
```